# Sending office365 emails through R / Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, outlook, smtp

I'm trying to send emails using R, which will eventually be deployed in a Shiny application. I've got an Office 365 account which is able to send email if I log into it but using the SMTP server I'm not getting any connection so far.

I've tried packages mailR & emayili but I'm not getting anywhere for some reason. I've used our local mail server before and that worked but that won't work for a shiny deployment.

According to Outlook I'm supposed to use:

Server name: smtp.office365.com
Port: 587
Encryption method: STARTTLS

But I can't seem to find a package that can do STARTTLS encryption. For other mail providers I see the advice to turn on "less secure apps" but that's not an option for us.

Example code :

```
library(mailR)

send.mail(from = "Me@companydomain.com",
          to = c("you@companydomain.com"),
          subject = "Test",
          body = "TEST",
          smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.office365.com",
                      port = 587,
                      user.name = "Me@companydomain.com",
                      passwd = "SuperSecretPassword",
                      tls = TRUE),
          authenticate = TRUE,
          send = TRUE,
          debug = TRUE)

# Another option, with emayili:

library(emayili)

smtp <- server(host = "smtp.office365.com",
               port = 587,
               username = "Me@companydomain.com",
               password = "SuperSecretPassword")

email <- envelope(from = "Me@companydomain.com",
                  to = "you@companydomain.com",
                  subject = "This is a plain text message!",
                  text = "Hello!")

smtp(email, verbose = TRUE)
```

I really hope someone figured out a package that can use STARTTLS or how to encrypt in that way using one of these packages!

Best Regards,

Bob

Comment: Are you using mailR version 0.8? They changed the internal argument used, perhaps updating will help.

Comment: FYI, the `blastula` package works sending email with STARTLTS through smtp.office365.com.

Comment: Maybe our IT department didn't set up the MFA exemption yet, so haven't got a successful connection so far but will report back once they've cleared that part up so I can test blastula. Which argument changed for mailR?

Comment: Solved this one using blastula in the end with smtp_send function.